# Is it possible to have two different Spring Batch JobRegistry configured against two different JobRepositories?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I have an application where I have configured two different jobRepository(ies) for different category of jobs; now I want to run all jobs of one category. I tried using JobRegistry but it has jobs from both the job repositories.
How can I get the names of all jobs of a particular job repository?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between `JobRepository` and `JobRegistry` concepts.

> now I want to run all jobs of one category

Spring [bean profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles) look a good option for you here. You can create a profile for each category and choose which job profile (category) to run.